# Pycharm Jupyter notebook not working after switch to Apple silicon pycharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I switched the Pycharm on my Mac to the Apple silicon version, and the Pycharm Jupyter notebook just not running.

Here are some relevant information:

Only the Jupyter notebook based on system environment interpreter failed. Other virtual environment interpreter works fine

When I tried to start the Jupyter server, it takes quite a bit of time and returns a pop up that said: Run Error.

Another pop up on the right down corner said: pycharm server http://localhost:8888 is not responding. pycharm is trying to reestablish a connection to it. some execution results might be lost.

Here's the log (or console?) of the Jupyter notebook:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.11 -m jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=##ROUTE TO MY NOTEBOOK FILE## --no-browser
[I 17:39:04.326 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: ##ROUTE TO MY NOTEBOOK FILE##
[I 17:39:04.326 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.5.4 is running at:
[I 17:39:04.326 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=6bd99a7417122390161cb13507d09b8ec08717d2b3d90403
[I 17:39:04.326 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=6bd99a7417122390161cb13507d09b8ec08717d2b3d90403
[I 17:39:04.326 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 17:39:04.328 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///Users/zhxinyang/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-3109-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=6bd99a7417122390161cb13507d09b8ec08717d2b3d90403
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=6bd99a7417122390161cb13507d09b8ec08717d2b3d90403
[I 17:39:04.329 NotebookApp] 302 GET /api/kernelspecs/ (127.0.0.1) 0.680000ms
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[I 17:39:04.364 NotebookApp] 302 GET /api/kernelspecs/ (127.0.0.1) 0.190000ms
[I 17:39:04.389 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 234e8764-2dbf-42cf-b530-65ccca143708, name: python3
[W 17:39:04.394 NotebookApp] No session ID specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .comm.comm import BaseComm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .comm import Comm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 35, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 123, in <module>
    from . import _psosx as _psplatform
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _psposix
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psposix.py", line 28, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_osx
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
[I 17:39:07.381 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .comm.comm import BaseComm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .comm import Comm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 35, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 123, in <module>
    from . import _psosx as _psplatform
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _psposix
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psposix.py", line 28, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_osx
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
[I 17:39:10.406 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .comm.comm import BaseComm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .comm import Comm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 35, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 123, in <module>
    from . import _psosx as _psplatform
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _psposix
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psposix.py", line 28, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_osx
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
[I 17:39:13.432 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .comm.comm import BaseComm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .comm import Comm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 35, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 123, in <module>
    from . import _psosx as _psplatform
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _psposix
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psposix.py", line 28, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_osx
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
[I 17:39:16.456 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .comm.comm import BaseComm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .comm import Comm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 35, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 123, in <module>
    from . import _psosx as _psplatform
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _psposix
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psposix.py", line 28, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_osx
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
[I 17:39:19.476 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (5/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .comm.comm import BaseComm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .comm import Comm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 35, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 123, in <module>
    from . import _psosx as _psplatform
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _psposix
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psposix.py", line 28, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_osx
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
[W 17:39:22.502 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 17:39:22.503 NotebookApp] Kernel 234e8764-2dbf-42cf-b530-65ccca143708 died, removing from map.
[W 17:40:04.396 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 234e8764-2dbf-42cf-b530-65ccca143708
[E 17:40:04.398 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 234e8764-2dbf-42cf-b530-65ccca143708)
```

Finally here's some information about the device I'm using:

Computer: MacBookPro 2023

CPU&GPU: M2 Max

Memory: 64GB

Python interpreter(System environment):Python 3.11

I'm totally clueless about this error and really appreciate if someone can help on it.

I tried to reinstall the Jupyter notebook but it doesn't work at all.